# Sqoop Export Oozie Workflow Fails with File Not Found, Works when ran from the console

Tags: hadoop, hive, oozie, sqoop, hue

I have a hadoop cluster with 6 nodes.  I'm pulling data out of MSSQL and back into MSSQL via Sqoop. Sqoop import commands work fine, and I can run a sqoop export command from the console (on one of the hadoop nodes).  Here's the shell script I run:

```
SQLHOST=sqlservermaster.local
SQLDBNAME=db1
HIVEDBNAME=db1
BATCHID=
USERNAME="sqlusername"
PASSWORD="password"


sqoop export --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://'$SQLHOST';username='$USERNAME';password='$PASSWORD';database='$SQLDBNAME'' --table ExportFromHive --columns col1,col2,col3 --export-dir /apps/hive/warehouse/$HIVEDBNAME.db/hivetablename
```

When I run this command from an oozie workflow, and it's passed the same parameters, I receive the error (when digging into the actual job run logs from the yarn scheduler screen):

```
**2015-10-01 20:55:31,084 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl: Job init failed
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hadoopnode1:8020/user/root/.staging/job_1443713197941_0134/job.splitmetainfo
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.createSplits(JobImpl.java:1568)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.transition(JobImpl.java:1390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl.handle(JobImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$JobEventDispatcher.handle(MRAppMaster.java:1312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceStart(MRAppMaster.java:1080)
    at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.start(AbstractService.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$4.run(MRAppMaster.java:1519)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1448)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://hadoopnode1:8020/user/root/.staging/job_1443713197941_0134/job.splitmetainfo
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.split.SplitMetaInfoReader.readSplitMetaInfo(SplitMetaInfoReader.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.job.impl.JobImpl$InitTransition.createSplits(JobImpl.java:1563)
    ... 17 more**
```

Has anyone ever seen this and been able to troubleshoot it? It only happens from the oozie workflow.  There are similar topics but no one seems to have solved this specific problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by setting the user.name property on the job.properties file for the oozie workflow to the user yarn.

```
user.name=yarn
```

I think the problem was it did not have permission to create the staging files under /user/root.  Once I modified the running user to yarn, the staging files were created under /user/yarn which did have the proper permission.

Comment: I have the exact same problem but this didn't work, it still creates the job dirs under root's .staging dir.

I'm running the oozie WF job as 'root', should I be doing it with 'yarn'?

Comment: In my case I was kicking off the job as user root, but setting the user.name in the job.properties file to yarn, which then created the staging directory under yarn and solved the issue I was seeing.

Comment: Hmm, this worked for me if I run the job from the Oozie CLI as 'yarn' because it kept creating the .staging directory under /user/root/. Anyway, thanks!